# Batch create videos - how to go about this

Tags: video, automation, batch-processing, video-editing

**I looked for a solution but found nothing. I have:**

- A video file
- A list of 100 addresses in addresses.csv

**I need to:**

- Generate one movie for each one of the addresses
- The movie should contain the address superimposed at some point within the movie. I want to create personalised holiday greeting movies.

**I would like to automate the process, here is what I thought:**

- Use iMovie and automate the process through applescript (insert a title, render movie, next one...) however applescript seems to be dead
- Build a gimp script that creates individual frames with the title
- Use imagemagick to create a bash script which creates the individual frames
- Work with Sikuli but that seems quite cumbersome for the task at hand...

Now on to my question: is there **a simpler way** to go about this? I cannot imagine that creating individual frames and then stitching them together into one video is the simplest way of automating this. I assume there has to be either a scriptable video editing tool or something made for the task of batch-generating a customised video? I didn't find anything and I am trying to use open source tools where possible...

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find anything to automate this?

Comment: Could you please share your Sikuli code. It should be quite easy if you are using the tool properly